# concatenation string in postgresql

Tags: string, postgresql

I have table:

```
temp_tbl
| code   |  name  |
|--------|--------|
| 1      |  name1 |
| 2      |  name2 |
| 3      |  name3 |
```

My function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION teststring()
  RETURNS character varying  AS
$BODY$DECLARE
    strReturn character varying = '';
    flag int = 0;
BEGIN
   flag = (select count(*) from temp_tbl);

   while flag > 0 Loop
      strReturn = strReturn ||';'|| (select name from temp_tbl);
      flag = flag - 1;
   end loop;

   RETURN strReturn;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

How can I return a string like that: `strReturn = "name1;name2;name3".`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select string_agg(name, ';')
from temp_tbl
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: Yes, exactly that.